# How to exclude some string in Regex using Javascript?

Tags: regex

I have meteor application where i need to fetch some data from backend, data sample is like

```
abc_xgsh_h_ssss
abc_xgsh_llll
abc_dfh_h_ssss
abc_xgsh_o_ssss
abc_xgsh_xyz_ssss
abc_ufvu_o_ssss
abc_xgsh_fgh_sss
abc_xgsh_mmm
```

I'm getting the above data when execute below command:

```
db.test.distinct('fieldName',{ "fieldName": { $regex: /\B(llll|mmmm|(?!h|o)_ssss)/i}});
```

What i want is below results,

```
abc_xgsh_llll
abc_xgsh_xyz_ssss
abc_xgsh_fgh_sss
abc_xgsh_mmm
```

How can i get the regex right? is my query wrong or how should i form it?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to match. from your examples I would say`abc_xgsh(_[a-z]+)?_\w+`

Comment: How can you expect `abc_xgsh_fgh_sss` and `abc_xgsh_mmm` if your pattern only matches `ssss` and `mmmm`? Remove one `m` and `s` then in your pattern. And replace `(?!h|o)` with `(?:[^ho])`

Comment: I have tried many combination but not succeeded in getting the result, and please don't down vote a question if you don't understand, or unclear of the answer. I'm won't be able to comment in other question if u down vote. Regarding question the **llll, mmmm** , ssss** are common, i want to fetch all these strings except string  having ** h_ssss, o_ssss**. How to exclude from match?

Comment: thank you @WiktorStribiżew ...I got it right..much appreciated!!

Comment: @Snkini Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting/upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the obvious problem with the number of `s` and `m` in the expected matches (your pattern requires 4 `m`s or `s`s while there are 3 in the expected matches) there is an issue with `(?!h|o)_`. This pattern means that you want to match `_` that is neither `h` nor `o`, which is certainly always true.

What you want is to match any char but `h` and `o` before `_`, or the start of the string. Change it to `[^ho]_` (it does not allow `_` to match at the start of the string) or `(?:^|[^ho])_` (where `^|` alternative allows matching at the string start).